# How to return a result-set from second select statement in a procedure?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

How can I return a result-set from a second select statement

I have the sample:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getGender20`(in id INT)
BEGIN
 DECLARE str VARCHAR(50);
  select @str :=gender from memeber_info where id=id;
if (str = 'Male') then
select '12345' ;
end if;
select '123' ;
END
```

My procedure is retuning `male` while I need it to return `123`. How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without a variable by using `case`

```
select case when gender = 'Male'
            then 12345
            else 123
       end as some_name
from memeber_info
where id=id;
```

Comment: thanks for help but can i use second select query output in resultset

Comment: You can if you are using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php). Not sure about the other API's.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can get the next result set from the `Statement` using the [`getMoreResults`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults%28int%29) function. The method returns a boolean, which is true if more result sets are available.